# docker: синхронизация времени в контейнере с хостом

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

У меня запускается ряд процессов в докер-контейнерах.

Но время в логах указывается совсем не такое, как на хосте.

Я попробовал пересоздать контейнер, добавив в команду `docker run` параметр `-v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro`, как это советуют в [докер-форумах](https://forums.docker.com/t/synchronize-timezone-from-host-to-container/39116)

Но, к сожалению, это не привело к результату:

при выполнении `docker exec -it` в этот контейнер, команда date выводит опять время, не совпадающее со временем хоста. Хотя `cat /etc/timezone` выводт в контейнере ту же таймзону ( `Europe/Moscow` ), что и на хосте.

Не могли бы Вы мне подсказать, в какую сторону смотреть, чтобы найти решение проблемы?

(Теоретически, я мог бы в каждый контейнер включать какой то способ при запуске принудительно поставить время, пердварительно получив его из внешнего источника, но мне это кажется очень сложным способом.)

Спасибо.

Comment: А насколько не такое? На произвольный период или оно просто в utc

Comment: @KoVadim - на минус 4 часа, вполне возможно, что это и есть UTC - время. Тогда - как бы мне сказать, что нужно использовать "не UTC" - время?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

да просто передайте стандартную переменную окружения TZ с именем вашей часовой зоны:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm debian:10 date
Fri Dec 17 22:45:46 UTC 2021
$ docker run -ti --rm -e TZ=Europe/Moscow debian:10 date
Sat Dec 18 01:46:07 MSK 2021
```

или даже более универсально, не указывайте зону явно, а получите её название из файла:

```
docker run -ti --rm -e TZ=$(cat /etc/timezone) debian:10 date
Sat Dec 18 01:53:25 MSK 2021
```

Comment: Обалдеть! Спасибо, эта строка `-e TZ=$(cat /etc/timezone)` теперь будет везде вписана! Ну, как говорится, пока на грабли не наступишь - ходить по ним не научишься...

Comment: возможно, имеет смысл уже при создании образа указать нужное значение для переменной окружения TZ.

Comment: aleksandr barakin - спасибо за совет!

Comment: Есть еще один интересный момент, который всплыл, когда я стал переходить на alpine-образы. В них просто установить переменную окружения контейнера в нужную таймзону - не помогает. Потому, что альпаину нужно еще и "вручную" поставить пакет tzdata, как советуют вот здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996420/how-to-set-timezone-inside-alpine-base-docker-image

Comment: если пакет решительные оптимизаторы выкинули, то, естественно, что его установить надо.